# jQuery - function that can be used similiar to sessions?

Tags: jquery, session

I have the following code:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.remove-me').bind( "click", function() {
        jQuery('#booking-alert').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

This basically fades out a small window when the user clicks the '.remove-me' element.

What I would like to add to this is have it so if the user decides to hide the div, it knows the user has previously clicked and therefore no longer displays the element.

So `jQuery('#booking-alert').hide();`

Can this be done using sessions or is there another method for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store this preference in the localStorage of the browser.

You can check localStorage capability of the browser by using:

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you can use the getter & setter for localStorage to store and retrieve information.

```
//Getter
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");

// Setter
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

You can find more information on HTML5 storage here: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

So in your case you could do something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remove-me').bind( "click", function() {
         jQuery('#booking-alert').fadeOut(200);
         localStorage.removeme = true;

     });


    //code to not show it in the first place:
    if (localStorage.removeme)
    {
       //something to hide the element if it was previously removed:
       $('#booking-alert').css("display","none");  
    }

 });
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1a4otcs8/

Comment: Thanks for this, however I've just tried the above but it doesn't seem to be 'hiding' #booking-alert when I refresh the page @JanR

Comment: I changed `true` to a value, e.g. '1' - and now it is working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Amended my code and added a Fiddle, can you accept the answer as it might help other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with cookies, which does not require HTML5 support. If you do not already have the plugin, you can download it [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

```
//include plugin after the JQuery library
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('bookingalert') != 'true') {
        jQuery('.remove-me').bind( "click", function() {
            $.cookie('bookingalert', 'true'); //create the cookie when user clicks
            jQuery('#booking-alert').fadeOut(200);
        });
    }
});
```